# Words for scaring

Tags: word-request

All I know is that "boo" is used for scaring people/young children/etc.

But are there other words to use instead of "boo"?

Comment: Words that scare teenagers: Tidying, rent, bathtime

Comment: Words that scare adults:  "teenager".....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually scare someone, any loud noise might work.  These aren't really "words", but you might represent them in text as "Arrrh", "Waaaa" or similar.

These are not "lexical", but sounds that you might make.  Compare the word "grunt" with the sound of someone grunting, which might be represented as "urrgh"

As a word, "boo" is really the only one used. It indicates a more playful scare.  And remember it is also used in a different context to show dislike of a performance (eg shouting "boo" at a bad actor)